# Solr or Lucene like single application

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

Hello i have already working application for searching in database. In database I have like 50M indexed documents. There is any idea to run all together i mean i don't want solr on http? what should i do? it's better to use Lucene or EmbeddedSolrServer? Or maybe you have other solution?

[image]

I have already something like on 1st diagram and i want make this in single process

And if i will go in lucene can i use my indexes from solr?

solr-5.2.1
Tomcat v8.0

Comment: _Why_ do you want to make it a single process?

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommended to have one tomcat and deploy the application and solr.

If solr crashes then they are chances of getting downtime for the application. So its always better to run solr independently. Embedding solr is also not recommended.

The simplest, safest, way to use Solr is via Solr's standard HTTP interfaces. Embedding Solr is less flexible, harder to support, not as well tested, and should be reserved for special circumstances.

for reference http://wiki.apache.org/solr/EmbeddedSolr

Comment: But this project its part of aplication and we need all this in 1 java proces

Comment: So I have to try use licene I guess?

Comment: Maybe you have any experience with Lucene and you know it's possible to use solr index on lucene? Because I can have indexing in solr on separated application

Comment: i dont any experience with lucene..but i think that is achievable as Solr is basically a wrapper around the lucene functionality, making things a little easier (like providing an administration interface). If you are using Solr, you are by definition using the lucene search engine....You can give a try with it if you have ample amount of time otherwise I would suggest ...use Lucene only for indexing as well...

Comment: I have alot of time xD I'm trainee and i have to check best solution :) Thenks alot for answer

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you want to use parts of the Solr feature set (Solr adds quite a few features on top of Lucene), you'll reimplement features that you otherwise would get for free.

You can use EmbeddedSolr to have Solr internal to your application, and then use the [`EmbeddedSolrServer`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_2_1/solr-core/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/embedded/EmbeddedSolrServer.html) client in `SolrJ` to talk to it - the rest of your application would still use Solr as it were a remote instance.

The problem with EmbeddedSolr is that you'll run into scalability issues as the index size grows, since you'll have a harder time scaling onto multiple servers and to separate concerns.